# How should I pass a Spark SQL DataFrame as an argument in Python function?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark SQL DataFrame within Jupyter notebook as `output_df1`. I want to define a function as follows:

```py
def output_agg(output_table_1):
    output_agg_1 = spark.sql(f"""
    select * from {output_table_1}
    """)
    return output_agg_1
```

When I call `output_agg(output_df1)`, I get the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:

/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o110.sql.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
mismatched input '['  expecting <EOF>
```

Can you please help with the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spark sql `select` needs to give table/temporary table. Register the dataframe as a temporary table first, and then execute the SQL statement.

```
output_df1.createOrReplaceTempView('output_table')
def output_agg(output_table_1):
    output_agg_1 = spark.sql(f"""
    select * from {output_table_1}
    """)
    return output_agg_1
output_agg('output_table')
```

I cannot add comment to completed questions. The information for learning Spark SQL is the Spark SQL Reference. `https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref.html`

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much! I was missing the '' in "output_agg('output_table')"

Answer (score 0):

Print the SQL query before passing to `spark.sql` and check if SQL query looks good. Also, share the SQL query in question.

```py
def output_agg(output_table_1):
    query = f"""select * from {output_table_1}"""
    print(query)
    output_agg_1 = spark.sql(query)
    return output_agg_1
```

If the SQL query looks good, then possible issues can be table is not registered with spark.

As discussed in the comments, since you want to union multiple dfs, you can do something like this

```py
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

dfs_list = [output_df1, output_df2, output_df3, output_df4]
df_combined = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, dfs_list)
```

**NOTE: Make sure the columns in all the df are in same order**

Comment: The SQL query is f"""select * from {output_table_1}"""

I think the way I I am calling {output_table_1} is not correct. I am unable to figure out how to call this argument in the SQL query. Even the Select * query is not working.

Comment: ```
def output_agg(output_table_1):
    query = f"""select * from {output_table_1}"""
    print(query)
    output_agg_1 = spark.sql(query)
    return output_agg_1
```

I meant print the query formed using this.

Comment: Oh ok. Here's the printed query:

select * from DataFrame[var1: string, var2: string, var3: bigint, var4: double, var5: string, var6: int]

Comment: Okay, so that is invalid SQL query. Can you add more details what are you trying to do ? Why are you passing a df here ? The correct SQL query should be like this `SELECT * FROM <table_name>`. If you can add more details what exactly are you doing with passed df, I can help.

Comment: I have 'n' Spark SQL DataFrames. This 'n' is a variable. Based on these n tables, I need to join them together and create a final Spark SQL dataframe. Since I don't know the exact value of n as it will change in the future, I thought creating a function would be helpful. These dataframes are in 100s of billions of rows. So Pandas dataframe is giving a memory error. Hence, using Spark SQL dataframe. Thanks for the prompt responses btw.

Comment: What is `output_df1` which is passed?  You want to join many such tables like `output_df1`, `output_df2`, `output_df3`, `output_df4`, ..... `output_df<n>` ?

Comment: output_df1 is one of 'n' tables. Yes, your understanding is correct. output_df1 union all output_df2 union all output_df3.......

Comment: Added the code snippet in the answer. Try that.

Comment: It worked. Thank you! However, is there any way I can call these tables as an argument in a Python function?

Comment: But what exactly you will do inside the function? You don't need to read the table there again, it is already loaded.

Comment: Your argument makes sense. Someone who assigned me this task suggested this. Hence, I wanted to try it out.